Mock being ignored, jest node
I'm trying mock a database with this test but the mock seems to be ignored. I can't think of a reason this could be?
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

jest.mock('../database', () => ({
  insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
}));

import database from '../database';

describe('create', () => {
  test('creates an enquiry if valid', () => {
    database.insert({ email: 'email@test.com' });
    expect(database.insert).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: 'email@test.com',
    });
  });
});

This is on node with typescript. On run I get this error so I'm fairly confident the mock is just being ignored:
 FAIL  models/enquiryModel.test.js
  create
    ✕ creates an enquiry if valid (2 ms)

  ● create › creates an enquiry if valid

    expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]

      47 |   test('creates an enquiry if valid', () => {
      48 |     database.insert({ email: 'email@test.com' });
    > 49 |     expect(database.insert).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
         |                             ^
      50 |       email: 'email@test.com',
      51 |     });
      52 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous> (models/enquiryModel.test.js:49:29)

jest.config.js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} **/
export default {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
};


It's because you're importing the default export, but mocking what would be a named export. To correct this, you need to move your mock object into a property called default.
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import database from '../database';

// Doesn't need to be above the import statement
jest.mock('../database', () => ({
  default: {
    insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  }
}));

describe('create', () => {
  test('creates an enquiry if valid', () => {
    database.insert({ email: 'email@test.com' });
    expect(database.insert).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: 'email@test.com',
    });
  });
});

